# PHP: Only execute calculation if all variables exist — without using conditional

Tags: php, if-statement

So I've got this bulk of routine calculations to make before saving some user input to the database.

```
    $cData['cCashFlow'] = $uData['uMonthlyIncome'] - $uData['uMonthlyExpenses'];
    $cData['cLiquidAssets'] = $uData['uCashSavings'] + $uData['uRetirementSavings'] + $uData['uOtherInvestments'];
    $cData['cDebt'] = $uData['uStudentLoans'] + $uData['uCreditCardDebt'] +$uData['uAutoLoanDebt'] + $uData['uOtherDebt'];
    $cData['cConsumerDebt'] = $uData['uCreditCardDebt'] + $uData['uAutoLoanDebt'] + $uData['uOtherDebt'];
    $cData['cLiquidNetWorth'] = $cData['cLiquidAssets'] - $cData['cDebt'];
    $cData['cMonthlyDebt'] = $uData['uStudentLoanPayments'] + $uData['uAutoLoanPayments'] + $uData['uCreditCardPayments'] + $uData['uOtherDebtPayments'];
    $cData['cHomeEquity'] = $uData['uHomeValue'] - $uData['uMortgageBalance'];
    $cData['cNetWorth'] = $cData['cLiquidNetWorth'] + $cData['cHomeEquity'];
```

`$cData` is the calculated data and `$uData` comes from the user.

Some calculations won't be performed on each save, because the user may not have filled in all the fields.

Of course I can just wrap each calculation in a conditional:

```
if($uData['uMonthlyIncome'] && $uData['uMonthlyExpenses']) :
    $cData['cCashFlow'] = $uData['uMonthlyIncome'] - $uData['uMonthlyExpenses'];
endif;
```

But it just gets really messy and labor intensive, especially if I have to add more of these calculations.

Is there an easy way to perform a calculation like this *only if all variables in the calculation exists*?

Comment: So what you want is a way of testing that all these fields actually exist with a value, without testing if all these fields exist with a value. Thats what programmers write... programs

Comment: Yes, basically. It seems repetitive to have to type out `if _this_ exists and _that_ exists and _theother_ exists, then _this_ + _that_ + _theother_`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make conditions more semantic by wrapping it into a function (expecting it's in a class):

```
private $uData;

private function isFilled()
{
    // get all function arguments as an array
    $args = func_get_args();
    // check each argument as an index to uData is empty 
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if (empty($this->uData[$arg])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public function process()
{
    $this->uData = $uData;

    if ($this->isFilled('uMonthlyIncome', 'uMonthlyExpenses')) {
        // do the calculations
         $cData['cCashFlow'] = $this->uData['uMonthlyIncome'] - $this->uData['uMonthlyExpenses'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I ended up starting with this and adding a little more (details as separate answer), but this was clearly the direction to go in.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think there is anything significantly better. You can extend it for example to do also calculations itself.

Comment: BTW consider marking any answer as the accepted answer, to help others find a solution more easily, please.

Answer (score 0):

if the point is to mantain a readable code you can just use the inline condition and use the alignment to get away from the mess..

```
$cData['cCashFlow']     = isset($uData['uMonthlyIncome']) && !empty($uData['uMonthlyIncome']) ? $uData['uMonthlyIncome'] - $uData['uMonthlyExpenses']                               : null;
$cData['cLiquidAssets'] = isset($uData['uCashSavings'])   && !empty($uData['uCashSavings'])   ? $uData['uCashSavings'] + $uData['uRetirementSavings'] + $uData['uOtherInvestments'] : null;
```

still clean right? As said you can wrap the conditions in one function that receive the keys that must be checked and return a boolean.

Comment: If the `$uData` comes from an HTML form, it'll be always `isset`, you have to use the `empty` function.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy ... unless it's a value from a radio button, checkbox or textarea field.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only checking if the first variable in the calculation exits.

Comment: @ibhhvc So just add other checks into a condition the same way as you had it in your original condition, where's the problem? But I doubt it will be more readable (actually I think the opposite).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

I built a callback function to complement array_sum:

```
function array_subtract($array){
  $result = $array[0];
  foreach($array as $key => $value) :
    if($key !== 0) :
      $result -= $value;
    endif;
  endforeach;

  return $result;
}
```

Then, I built a function to check all input variables and then process the calculation if all inputs exist:

```
public function calculator($function, $args){
  foreach ($args as $arg) :
    if($arg === null) :
      return null;
    endif;
  endforeach;

  return $function($args);
}
```

Then I called the "checker" function and input the callback function and the data as an array:

```
$cData['cCashFlow'] = $this->calculator('array_subtract', array($uData['uMonthlyIncome'], $uData['uMonthlyExpenses']));
$cData['cLiquidAssets'] = $this->calculator('array_sum', array($uData['uCashSavings'], $uData['uRetirementSavings'], $uData['uOtherInvestments']));
$cData['cDebt'] = $this->calculator('array_sum', array($uData['uStudentLoans'], $uData['uCreditCardDebt'], $uData['uAutoLoanDebt'], $uData['uOtherDebt']));
$cData['cConsumerDebt'] = $this->calculator('array_sum', array($uData['uCreditCardDebt'] + $uData['uAutoLoanDebt'] + $uData['uOtherDebt']));
$cData['cLiquidNetWorth'] = $this->calculator('array_subtract', array($cData['cLiquidAssets'], $cData['cDebt']));
$cData['cMonthlyDebt'] = $this->calculator('array_sum', array($uData['uStudentLoanPayments'], $uData['uAutoLoanPayments'], $uData['uCreditCardPayments'], $uData['uOtherDebtPayments']));
$cData['cHomeEquity'] = $this->calculator('array_subtract', array($uData['uHomeValue'], $uData['uMortgageBalance']));
$cData['cNetWorth'] = $this->calculator('array_sum', array($cData['cLiquidNetWorth'], $cData['cHomeEquity']));
```

If all input values for each calculation don't exist, NULL gets stored to the database, which is exactly what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
<?php
$uData = array();
@$uData['bla'] = $_POST['bla'];
@$uData['blaa'] = $_POST['blaa'];
@$uData['blaaa'] = $_POST['blaaa'];

$userInputs = array('bla', 'blaa', 'blaaa');

function checkUserInput($Inputs, $uData){
foreach($Inputs as $value){
    if($uData[$value] == null){
         return false;
    }
}
return true;
}

if(checkUserInput($userInputs, $uData) == true)
{
    echo "All here!";
}
```

Comment: **Dont use `@` to silence errors** They are errors for a reason, the reason being to inform you that what you do with these variables probably wont be right

Comment: @RiggsFolly if he gets the data from a form and not all fields are set than this actually makes sense

Comment: @Tewdyn - no, it doesn't. Use `!empty()` instead; I can think of no instance where error suppression in the code is a good thing.